# Integer presentation type in f-strings does not return expected format

Tags: python, docker, locale, string-formatting, f-string

I'm using python 3.8 in a Docker container. This is my docker file.

```
# Python image
FROM python:3.8.2-buster

# Install locales
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# it_IT.UTF-8 UTF-8/it_IT.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

#etc...
```

I wanna format numbers according to the Italian format (i.e., `.` as a thousands separator). Fortunately, the [format-specification-mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) says:

> The '`,`' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.
>   For a locale aware separator, use the '`n`' integer presentation type
>   instead.

I run this code inside such a container:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "it_IT.UTF-8")
>>> a = 10000000
>>> f'a is equal to {a:,}'
'a is equal to 10,000,000' # ok!
>>> f'a is equal to {a:n}'
'a is equal to 10000000'   # What!? I expected 'a is equal to 10.000.000' instead
```

but the last line behaves unexpectedly.

Where am I wrong? Is that a problem with my locale definition or with my usage of numbers formatting harnessing `n`?

Comment: @chepner `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "it_IT.UTF-8")` I'm gonna clarify this in the question. Thanks for your hint

Comment: No, that's what I get for only skimming the question :)

Comment: @chepner and all the people, it turned out that the problem was just a bad build of my container. Building it once again solved the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: What exactly did you do? I'm not even using docker, and I can't get the magic combination of locale settings that makes `f'{a:n}'` produce `10.000.000`.

Comment: @chepner I've just rebuilt the container and all worked fine. Please, note the locale installation at the beginning of my question. The `n` uses locale settings. So I believe It just depends on what locale your python is based on. Let me know if you figure that out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') 
a = 1000000    
print(f'{a:n}')  # => 1,000,000
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that does, but it's not a locale-aware formatting.

Comment: My original `LC_NUMERIC` value was set to `C`, which I believe is character and my result was the unformatted same as OP. Setting the locale with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,'')`  - which for me results in `'en_US.UTF-8'` and now produces the value - `'a is equal to 10,000,000'`.

Comment: the empty strings in setlocale() takes the system default locale.
anyhow, what do you see when you type: locale.localeconv()['mon_thousands_sep'] and locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep']? do u see ","?